# Mounting debian img issues, on the Kindle Fire [linuxonandroid]

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, amazon-kindle-fire

I've been stuck on this issue for about 2 months now.

Everytime I try too run LinuxOnAndroid I get the following error:

```
mount: mounting /dev/block/loop255 on /data/local/mnt: Invalid Argument.
```

My /proc/filesystems show I support:

```
  ext2
  ext3
  ext4
```

If I try too mount /dev/block/loop255 the with -t ext1 the error becomes

```
mount: mounting /dev/block/loop255 on /data/local/mnt: No such file or directory.
```

My /proc/config.gz shows my rom DOES support loop devices.

And, I'm using a Kindle Fire first GEN.

I have no idea what's going on, if it helps it used too run untill I had too hard reboot the tablet once. I have filled a bug report with LoA but havn't been gotten back too for 2 months so far.

Comment: Have you tried alternative [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en) installations? Could be an old version of `mount` tripping you up.

Comment: @Chahk I updated Busybox as my first thing I did.

Comment: @Chahk I'm starting too wonder if it's an issue with the image itself.